# Django - get objects having latest time in day

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I have a model `Scan`. There are multiple scans for each `Car` in one day.
Every scan has it's datetime.

EDIT: changed - datetime can be accessed right from scan object
EDIT2:

This approach works but it choose first scans in day, not last.

```
car.scans.filter(valid=True).distinct('date')
```

.

```
class Car...
    ...

class Scan...
    datetime = DateTimeField...
    scanning = ForeignKey('Scanning'...
    car = ForeignKey('Car'...
    value = IntegerField(...
    valid = BooleanField(...
```

Now I want to create a chart for a car. There will be days and values. For every day, there will be only one value (the latest valid).

Since there can be multiple scans a day, I want to get the last scan in a day.

Car
        Datetime
        Value
    
    
    

    
         1
         01.05.2017 01:00 am
         1
    

    
         1
          01.05.2017 02:00 am
         4
    

    
         1
          01.05.2017 04:00 am
         8
    

    
         1
          02.05.2017 01:00 am
         12
    
    
         1
          03.05.2017 01:00 am
         7
    
    
         1
          03.05.2017 02:00 am
         5
    

    
         1
          03.05.2017 03:00 am
         6
    
    
         1
          03.05.2017 08:00 am
         9

---

Result would be:

01.05.2017 - 8

02.05.2017 - 12

03.05.2017 - 9

Th only think I figured out is to get list of dates and for every date, get all scans - then pull the last scan.

But I'm trying to find a more effective way since there can be thousands of scans.

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach for read would be to have intermediate table to save last state for each car. It would involve some extra updating but in the end reading would be easy.

Other approach would be to use query with sub-select as this one

```
Scan.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('car__scan__datetime')).filter(date=F('max_date'))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Tried cars.scans.annotate(max_date=Max('date')).filter(date=F('max_date')) - there are multiple scans with one date (not datetime)

Comment: try following as first argument in Max car__scan__date

Comment: I've edited the question, there is a partial solution which gets first scan in day, not last. According to 'car__scan__datetime', it doesn't work. Tried 'car__scans__datetime' which returns empty queryset and it takes almost 20 seconds.